# Im a beginner and i need some help regarding this problem

Tags: c

> Design a program that allows a user to enter any quantity of numbers until a negative number is entered. Then display the highest number and the lowest number.

The problem is that I want to print the lowest positive number inputted but instead what comes up is the negative number.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
{
    float max;
    float number;
    float min;
 
    printf("Entering a negative number will terminate the sequence.\n");
    do
    { 
        printf("Enter Number:");
        (scanf("%f", &number));
        if(number>max)
        {
            max=number;
        }
        if(number<min)
        {
            min=number;
        }
    } while(number>=0);
    printf("Your largest number was %.3f. Your smallest number was %.3f.", max, min);
}
```

Comment: `number < min && number >= 0`. Or you could just set `float number = 0;` and it should work with only a while loop as well.

Comment: Please read the help center [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and change your question for a better title

Answer (score 1):

- You must not use values of uninitialized non-static local variables because they are indeteminate.
- You shouldn't treat negative input (end mark) as input and update min and max according to that.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main(void)
 
{ 
 
    float max;
    float number;
    float min;
    int inputExists = 0;
 
    printf("Entering a negative number will terminate the sequence.\n");
 
    for(;;)
    { 
    printf("Enter Number:");
    if (scanf("%f", &number) != 1 || number < 0) break;
    
        if(!inputExists || number>max)
        {
 
            max=number;
            }
 
        if(!inputExists || number<min)
        {
 
            min=number;
            }
 
         inputExists = 1;
 
    }
 
    if(inputExists)
    {
        printf("Your largest number was %.3f. Your smallest number was %.3f.", max, min);
        }
    else
    {
        puts("You gave no input.");
        }
 
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky This indentation is inherited from the original (before being edited) question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your min value gets change only if entered number is not 0. And, initialise max to 0, and min to 9999.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{ 
    float max=0;
    float number=0;
    float min=99999;
    
    printf("\nEntering a negative number will terminate the sequence");
    
    do { 
        printf("\nEnter Number : ");
        scanf("%f", &number);
        
        if(number>=0) {
            
            if(number>max)
            {
                max=number;
            }
            
            if(number<min)
            {
                min=number;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while(number>=0);

    printf("Your largest number was %.3f. Your smallest number was %.3f.", max, min);

}
```

Comment: Why use the magic number of `99999`? Are you sure it is big enough?  We have  macros like `FLT_MAX` or `INFINITY` for such cases.

Comment: @HAL9000 Sir I dont know what macros are? SO, I used this 'magic number'.

Comment: Macros in c is whatever you create with `#define`, they are implemented and interpreted by the c preprocessor. `FLT_MAX` is the largest float number that is an actual number. `INFINITY` is the only number larger than `FLT_MAX`, but is not considered an actual number. It is used to represent positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put another condition for the minimum value, then your problem will be solved. Like this:

```
do
    { 
        printf("Enter Number:");
        (scanf("%f", &number));
        if(number>max)
        {
            max=number;
        }
        
        // As if number is less then 0 then it is our terminaton condition
        // we don't need to update our min value
        if(number >= 0 && number<min)
        {
            min=number;
        }
    } while(number>=0);
```